# why not use translation API's instead of resource bundle approach?

Tags: java, translation, resourcebundle

I know when you know in advance your product will be used in these specific countries, then people should go for resource bundle approach. But when we are not for in how many countries our product may be launched in future at present, then why not go for translation api like provided by Google? Say if we plan to launch our product in a new country, then in resource bundle approach you have to make the entries for each label in text file. But with this translation approach, we can do make the files through translation apis at the start of server so that we can save rune time translation. Though I have not seen any project doing this as of now. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One major reason *not* to use automatic translation is quality - you don't want to only "translate" your app, you really want to "[localize](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18130/translation_vs_localization_and_those_other_long_words)" it.

And even if you just want to translate it, you want the result to have some meaning, which requires context - otherwise, you'll end up with menus/UI elements that have such weird texts the users will think your system is so crappy they'll stop using the translated version or worse, the system as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

Translation APIs, though useful, are unable to provide you with context in the application where as 'human generated' content in resourcebundles can.

Comment: sorry radimpe for not getting point. Can you little bit brief about the context we are talking about here

Comment: "Venetian Blind" - Does this refer to something covering your windows or to a "Blind man from Venice"?

Answer (score 2):

One good reason not to use the Google Transliteration API is that it has been [deprecated](http://code.google.com/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html).  Using a deprecated API in a new project doesn't strike me as a particularly wise move.

Comment: +1 and even if it wasn't deprecated, any dependency on an external service that *may* have reliability issues or disappear in the future is a risk to your product.

Comment: Thats valid point. But google api is just example. My main point is say if java comes up with transliteration api in future. Should we prefer it on resource bundle or not?